# Perform an action on Mobile Safari (after some time has passed)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

I'm working with HTML5 in Mobile Safari (iOS 6).
I want to execute a JavaScript code after some time has passed.
For example to redirect to another page after 60 seconds.

Is it possible?

Comment: this is a basic javascript question, no need for anything special because its mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute your code one time only, after 60 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        /* your code here */
},60000);​
```

While this

```
setInterval(function() {
        /* your code here */
},60000);​
```

Will execute your code **every** 60 seconds

Comment: as he said, to redirect you just need this:  setTimeout(function() { document.location='gohere.html'; },6000);

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to indicate something. I need to run the code after 60 seconds, when the user does not perform any action. In this case it's a time without the user performs a touch. In desktop browser, i can capture keyboard or mouse inactivity. I need to know what event inactivity capture (in MObile Devices).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/ ?